# How are XML and JSON used in conjunction with SQL?

Tags: sql, ajax, xml, json

I've done a lot of googling as to what JSON is, and how it is used on the web. I understand that it is a way of storing data using Javascript object notation, and that it is a lightweight way to store data and is therefore preferable to XML.

However, I don't quite understand exactly how XML and JSON are used to transmit data in the first place, especially when using SQL. Is SQL data loaded into an XML file/JSON string and then displayed with Ajax?

I know this is a complete newbie question but I am seriously confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML and JSON are *serialisation formats*. They're plain text formats which allow you to express more than plain text. JSON can express complex nested hierarchies of arrays and key-value objects, XML can express even more complex object-attribute-value-content hierarchies. Both data formats simply allow you to send more than a simple string in a defined way.

In more practical terms, how would you send *three* items from A to B? You can easily send just "foo", it's just a string. But what about "foo", "bar" and "baz"? Do you want to invent your own serialisation format? Like:

```
foo,bar,baz
```

Then you do some string processing on the other end to split by `,` to get your three elements back? What if you need to send more complex data? What if your data contains a ","? That's where existing serialisation standards come in, like JSON and XML. You don't need to answer all those questions every time from scratch, you just use an existing, well supported standard:

```
["foo","bar","baz"]
```

or:

```
<data>
    <item>foo</item>
    <item>bar</item>
    <item>baz</item>
</data>
```

You would generate this data on the fly as needed; a database can be one possible source for this data. You don't "put it in a file", you output it as needed. Pseudo code example:

```
var data = []
while (row = fetch_from_database())
    data.push(row.name)
var json = json_encode(data)
print json
```

Here you're creating an array `data` with the contents of the `name` column of your database, then encode it to JSON and output it. The output will be something like the "foo", "bar", "baz" example from above.

Comment: Ok, so you would store xml or json data as a single entry in a mysql database as opposed to creating a column in your table for every single piece of data you want to store? Like if I was storing data in a mysql table for a blog application, and I knew that I was never going to want to search the database for post titles and content individually, I could use json or xml to store both the title and the content in the same string?

Comment: Uhm... *jein*... Storing XML or JSON in a relational database it typically a bad idea. Yes, it can be done, and yes, sometimes it makes sense. But no, it should not be your first instinct. Store the data in your database the way that it makes the most sense and that best fits a relational database. If you want to, say, get that data out of your database via AJAX into Javascript, or via a RESTful API into any other system, then you package it as JSON or XML in order to send it over the wire.

Comment: So if you were to use AJAX to update data in an SQL database and then dynamically update the HTML, the PHP file you sent the request to would format the data from SQL as JSON and then send it back?

Comment: Yes, exactly. JSON would just be used as the data format *between* Javascript and PHP. It's a *"wire format"*; some specified way to transport structured data between two separate entities. How else would you be sending a *PHP array* to Javascript and have it become a *Javascript array*? Of course you *can* use JSON in a number of other scenarios, but this is its primary use.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of JSON and XML as a manner in which an object is written down. So for example, say I would give you some random book and I would ask you to describe to me what makes up that book, what would you say?

Probably, you would name the title, author, publisher and other characteristics of the book that identify that book as being that book. So in essence, what you do is describe to me in words what JSON or XML do in their syntax. JSON and XML are ways to represent objects.

SQL is a way to logically store and search for information. A SQL database may contain objects, and with SQL you can search, store and retrieve (etc.) these objects.

Ajax is a means to transfer information (asynchronously). With Ajax you can transfer the information of an object (a JSON or XML object for example) between systems/applications.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is used to store data.  XML and JSON are human readable, text based, data transport protocols. 
Typically a request is made either via HTTP or AJAX. The App that receives the request retrieves the data from an SQL database.  The requested data is formatted into XML or JSON then transmitted to the requester as the Response.
XML and JSON can contain all the elements of a database. The original purpose of XML was to transfer data between two systems with dissimilar data storage. JSON was created as a simplified alternative to XML.  JSON is key-value pair oriented where a database column name is the key and the data stored in that column is the value associated with the key.
For example Google Geo Coding gives the option for their response to be formatted as JSON or XML.

**XML /geocode/xml/**

```
$data = @file_get_contents(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1234+Main+St&sensor=false);
```

This creates a very simple XML response.
**To get Latitude from the XML response:**

```
$xmldecode  = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$coordinates = $googlexml - > Response - > Placemark - > Point - > coordinates;
$coordinates = split(",", $coordinates);
$lat = $coordinates[1];
```

**JSON  /geocode/json/**

```
$data = @file_get_contents(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1234+Main+St&sensor=false);
```

To get Latitude from the JSON response:

```
  $json = json_decode($data,true);
  $lat = $json['results']['0']['geometry']['location']['lat'];
```

An SQL record can be converted to JSON
**Sample mySQL Export to JSON**

```
 {"number": 9547839995,
"TimeStamp": "2014-10-09 21:38:10",
"ip": "",
"business": "Creative R Us Computer & Phone Repair",
"addr": "547 E Sample Rd",
"city": "Pompano Beach,
  FL 33064",
"email": "",
"exp": "",
"web": "http://www.creativerus.com",
"name": "",
"note": ""}]
```

Now an XML mySQL Export gives a lot more detail.
**Sample mySQL Export to XML**

```
<pma_xml_export version="1.0" xmlns:pma="http://www.phpmyadmin.net/some_doc_url/">
    <!--
    - Structure schemas
    -->
    <pma:structure_schemas>
        <pma:database name="isl_contact" collation="latin1_swedish_ci" charset="latin1">
            <pma:table name="Profile">
                CREATE TABLE `Profile` (
                  `number` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                  `TimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                  `ip` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                  `business` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
                  `addr` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
                  `city` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
                  `email` char(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                  `exp` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
                  `web` char(128) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
                  `name` char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
                  `note` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                  KEY `NUMBER` (`ip`,`state`)
                ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=369 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
            </pma:table>
        </pma:database>
    </pma:structure_schemas>

    <!--
    - Database: 'isl_contact'
    -->
    <database name="isl_contact">
        <!-- Table Profile -->
        <table name="Profile">
            <column name="number">9545555555</column>
            <column name="TimeStamp">2014-10-09 21:38:10</column>
            <column name="ip"></column>
            <column name="business">Creative R Us Computer</column>
            <column name="addr">547 E Sample Rd</column>
            <column name="city">Pompano Beach,  FL 33064</column>
            <column name="email"></column>
            <column name="exp"></column>
            <column name="web">http://www.creativerus.com</column>
            <column name="name"></column>
            <column name="note"></column>
            <column name="link"></column>
            <column name="contact"></column>
            <column name="source"></column>
            <column name="id">1</column>
            <column name="mobile"></column>
            <column name="state">3</column>
            <column name="attributes">0</column>
            <column name="fuDate">NULL</column>
            <column name="fuTime">NULL</column>
        </table>
    </database>
</pma_xml_export>
```

[http://php.net/manual/en/xml.examples.php][1]